# Gradient of squared dot product

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^d$. What is

$$\nabla_x\langle x,y\rangle^2$$

I know that we have

$$
\nabla_x\langle x,x\rangle^2 = \|x\|^2 = 2x
$$
but how this changes for the case $\langle x,y\rangle^2$?

Comment: It is no big deal to find $y$ by expanding the product.

Comment: It's even a smaller deal when coordinates are avoided and just chain and product rule are used. And your gradient of $\langle x,x\rangle^2$ is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$\begin{align}d_p\langle x,y\rangle^2&=2\langle x,y\rangle\langle p,y\rangle\\
&=\langle2\langle x,y\rangle y,p\rangle,
\end{align}
$$
hence the gradient is $2\langle x,y\rangle y.$